# Probablity Theory Binomial Distribution Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, binomial-distribution

An urn contains 7 red and 11 white balls. Draw one
ball at random from the urn. Let X = 1 if a red ball is
drawn, and let X = 0 if a white ball is drawn. Give the
pmf, mean, and variance of X.

I got the pmf and the mean correct, however my variance answer is not matching up with the correct answer which is 77/324. Is this answer correct?

The formula I am using is x^2 f(x) - mean^2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathsf {Var}(X) = \frac {77}{324}$.

Which is indeed obtained by $\mathsf {Var}(X)~=~ 1^2{\cdot}\mathsf P(X=1)-(1{\cdot}\mathsf P(X=1))^2$.